# Create subfolders/zip every 20 files automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

I have a huge folder that I would like to transform into several small ones of 20 files each and compressed. I would like to do this automatically with a batch file and 7zip.

**To achieve this I thought about 2 steps**:

**1. Create a sub-folder for each 20 files** ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/1442270/batch-script-to-move-x-number-of-files-to-empty-folders)) :

```
@echo off
set /a counter=1
set /a filesperfolder=20
cd "C:\Users\Desktop\dir\"
:loopstart
set dirname=dir_%counter%
md %dirname%
echo %dirname%

dir /b | findstr /v /i "dir_*"> %temp%\temp.txt && for /l %%l in (1,1,%filesperfolder%) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^" %temp%\temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%%l:"') do @move %%b %dirname%\%%b >nul

set /a counter=%counter%+1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %temp%\temp.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set _filesmoved=%%a
del %temp%\temp.txt
IF %_filesmoved% LSS 20 goto done

goto loopstart

:done
cls
echo All files were moved!!
pause
exit
```

<s>Unfortunately this does not work : `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`. I've tried debugging the script by removing the `@echo off` and it tells me that the `dir /b | findstr /v /i "dir_*"> %temp%\temp.txt && for /l %%l in (1,1,%filesperfolder%) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^" %temp%\temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%%l:"') do @move %%b %dirname%\%%b >nul` part is not working (*same error*). This part is quite fuzzy for me and a little help would be welcome.

I specify that the file *temp.txt* contains my complete list of files, without any separator (one file per line).</s>

**--- UPDATE: filenames must not contain spaces ---**

**2. Compress all these subfolders one by one** with ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/94421/how-to-make-7-zip-do-a-whole-bunch-of-folders)) :
`for /D %d in (*.*) do 7z a -tzip "%d.zip" ".\%d\*"`

Do you have an idea for (I summarize) : **create, for a large number of files, subfolders of 20 files** in order to compress each subfolder one by one.

*If you have any idea on how to compress each 20 files directly (without going through the creation of subfolders) I also agree!*

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create folders. Just iterate over the files and add every single file to it's designated zip file (instead of copying every 20 files into a folder and zip that folder)
Use two counters to keep track of (source)files and zip files. One counter for the files (use the Modulo-operator to check for each 20) and one for the zip filenames. I started the zip filenames with `10001` instead of `1` and took the last four chars of it to get sortable file names (`0001.zip` etc).

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filesperfolder=20
cd /d "%cd%"
set "zipDest=C:\temp"
set filecounter=0
set foldercounter=10001

for %%a in (*) do (
  set /a filecounter+=1
  set /a check=filecounter %% filesperfolder
  if !check! == 0 set /a foldercounter+=1
  ECHO 7z a -tzip "%zipDest%\!foldercounter:~-4!.zip" "%%a"
)
```

Obviously adapt the `cd /d` line (source folder), destination folder (Attention: don't use the source folder, or your zip files might be zipped again into other zip files), and maybe the zip-filename (like `"%zipDest%\MyZips-!foldercounter:~-4!.zip"`)

NOTE: I disarmed the 7zip command with `ECHO` for testing and troubleshooting. Remove the `ECHO` when the output satisfies you.

To delete each file *after successfully zipping them*, change the zip line to:

```
7z a -tzip "%zipDest%\!foldercounter:~-4!.zip" "%%a" && del "%%a"
```

The quotes should take care of any spaces.

Comment: Oh thank you very much Stephan! This is totally what I wanted and I thank you for your teaching. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved!**
I found my mistake. In reality my files included spaces that the script could not fit.

So, to answer my basic question which was: **in a big folder filled with thousands of files, how to compress each 20 files in subfolders?** it is necessary (to my knowledge) to:

1. Create a sub-folder for each 20 files **whose name does not have spaces** (*code in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63635764/13130295)*)
2. Compress all these subfolders one by one (*code in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63635764/13130295)*)

And it's done!

Do not hesitate to suggest a solution if you know of a "faster" one.